# Is there a Postgrest API equivalent for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, postgresql, api, postgrest

I earlier worked on postgres sql database and created some functions there which i called using postgrest api via postman.

I want to do the exact same thing with mysql, does this even possible?.

Need to send get/post request by calling MySQL functions via postman or curl and fetch data from MySQL db.

Answer (score 1):

There is now:

https://github.com/subzerocloud/showcase/tree/main/node-myrest

It's a js/ts lib that implements 99% of what PostgREST does and you embed it it your js/express server that you can extend with your business logic

Answer (score 0):

There was an http plugin developed as a proof of concept for MySQL around 2014:

http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2014/mysql-5-7-http-plugin-mysql/

But I don't know if it is available anymore. I don't find a place where it can be downloaded.